# Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables (srcTable1 & destTable) that have identical schemas. I am trying to copy all rows from srcTable to destTable and ignore the duplicates. I thought I could just add a WHERE clause with a subquery that would give me only the rows that aren't duplicates. However, it doesn't seem to work. I don't get any rows inserted or selected.

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT * FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM destTable)
```

I realize I could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT * FROM srcTable
WHERE MyKey IN (SELECT MyKey FROM destTable)
```

However, my tables have multiple keys and I can't think of how you could do this with multiple keys.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what duplicates you are concerned about. Is the concern about inserting rows from source that are already in dest, rows that are duplicated in source, or both?

Comment: Are you using mysql or mssql?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your problem is that you need another where clause in the subquery that identifies what makes a duplicate:

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.Field1=destTable.Field1 and
                       SrcTable.Field2=DestTable.Field2...etc.)
                 )
```

As noted by another answerer, an outer join is probably a more concise approach. My above example was just an attempt to explain using your current query to be more understandible. Either approach could technically work.

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT s.field1,s.field2,s.field3,... 
FROM srcTable s 
       LEFT JOIN destTable d ON (d.Key1 = s.Key1 AND d.Key2 = s.Key2 AND...)
WHERE d.Key1 IS NULL
```

Both of the above approaches assume you are woried about inserting rows from source that might already be in destination. If you are instead concerned about the possibility that source has duplicate rows you should try something like.

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Distinct field1,field2,field3,... 
FROM srcTable
```

One more thing. I'd also suggest listing the specific fields on your insert statement instead of using SELECT *.

Comment: Your first solution did it.
A JOIN doesn't do it becuase any JOIN only returns rows that the 2 tables have in common. What I need are the rows the 2 tables don't have in common.

Comment: Actually the Join will work, but only an OUTER join. Note the condition that d.key1 IS NULL meaning you want unmatched rows. Of course you'd have to tweak that condition for what exactly constitutes a duplicate in your scenario.

Comment: @JohnFx The join worked well for me where I have a destination table with a slightly different structure.

Comment: @JohnFx what to do if there are duplicates but like record1 has 3 duplicate records. eg.Row1 has a record which has 30 columns, out of which 10 columns have data,remaining are null. Its duplicate row2 , 15 colums have data and remaining are null. here row2 is a duplicate of row1 but with more data. Again row3 has the same record but its 3 columns have the same data and remaining all are null. While inserting unique records from source table to destination table, how can I update the record with the row which has maximum values like here its row2 and remove other duplicate rows?

Comment: @iks_in I suggest you ask that as a separate question on the site since it is a bit of a divergence from OP's question.

Answer (score 23):

I realize this is old, but I got here from google and after reviewing the accepted answer I did my own statement and it worked for me hope someone will find it useful:

```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO destTable SELECT id, field2,field3... FROM origTable
```

Edit: This works on MySQL I did not test on MSSQL

Comment: For MySQL I needed to add distinct to this. full query: `INSERT IGNORE INTO destination_table (field, field1, field2) SELECT DISTINCT field, field1, field2  FROM origin_table`

Answer (score 10):

I hope this query will help you

```
INSERT INTO `dTable` (`field1`, `field2`)
SELECT field1, field2 FROM `sTable` 
WHERE `sTable`.`field1` NOT IN (SELECT `field1` FROM `dTable`)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for migrating data from an old framework version into a new framework version where some of the values had already been set and some were missing.

Comment: ...Though I did remove all the ` ` marks for my flavor of SQL interpreter.

Comment: I do not know why this answer has 11 positive votes as this is not doing what it suppose to do. I have a table with over 20mln emails (duplicates as well) and after running this query, I still have duplicates in new table...

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?:

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT s.* FROM srcTable s
LEFT JOIN destTable d ON d.Key1 = s.Key1 AND d.Key2 = s.Key2 AND...
WHERE d.Key1 IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. A join, whether it is INNER or OUTER, will only give me rows the 2 tables have in common. I need the rows they don't have in common. I still have found no answer to this.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works for you, but your statement is *not* correct. A LEFT (OUTER) JOIN will return all rows from the left-hand table, regardless of whether there is a matching row in the right-hand table. The WHERE clause eliminates all resulting rows where there is a match.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT ?

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM srcTable
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work.

DISTINCT will give me a list of distinct rows in the srcTable. What I need is a distinct list when the 2 tables are combined.

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT is the keyword you're looking for.

In MSSQL, copying unique rows from a table to another can be done like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
INTO newTable
FROM srcTable
```

The `column_name` is the column you're searching the unique values from.

Tested and works.

Comment: That might work if I were creating a new table, but the source table already exists, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Great answer. Good for starting off a project.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into tbl2
select field1,field2,... from tbl1
where not exists 
    ( 
        select field1,field2,... 
        from person2
        where (tbl1.field1=tbl2.field1 and
        tbl1.field2=tbl2.field2 and .....)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try first remove duplicates in the subquery?

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT source.* FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM srcTable
    EXCEPT
    SELECT src.* FROM
    srcTable AS src
    INNER JOIN destTable AS dest 
    /* put in below line the conditions to match repeated registers */
        ON dest.SOME_FANCY_MATCH = src.SOME_FANCY_MATCH AND ... 
) as source
```

If the sets are very large, maybe this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me with PHP / PDO.

```
public function createTrainingDatabase($p_iRecordnr){
// Methode: Create an database envirioment for a student by copying the original
// @parameter: $p_iRecordNumber,    type:integer,   scope:local
// @var: $this->sPdoQuery,          type:string,    scope:member 
// @var: $bSuccess,                 type:boolean,   scope:local
// @var: $aTables,                  type:array,     scope:local
// @var: $iUsernumber,              type:integer,   scope:local
// @var: $sNewDBName,               type:string,    scope:local
// @var: $iIndex,                   type:integer,   scope:local 

// -- Create first the name of the new database --
$aStudentcard = $this->fetchUsercardByRecordnr($p_iRecordnr);
$iUserNumber = $aStudentcard[0][3];
$sNewDBName = $_SESSION['DB_name']."_".$iUserNumber;
// -- Then create the new database  --
$this->sPdoQuery = "CREATE DATABASE `".$sNewDBName."`;";
$this->PdoSqlReturnTrue();
// -- Create an array with the tables you want to be copied --
$aTables = array('1eTablename','2ndTablename','3thTablename');
// -- Populate the database --
for ($iIndex = 0; $iIndex < count($aTables); $iIndex++) 
{
 // -- Create the table --
    $this->sPdoQuery = "CREATE TABLE `".$sNewDBName."`.`".$aTables[$iIndex]."` LIKE `".$_SESSION['DB_name']."`.`".$aTables[$iIndex]."`;";
    $bSuccess = $this->PdoSqlReturnTrue();
    if(!$bSuccess ){echo("Could not create table: ".$aTables[$iIndex]."<BR>");}
    else{echo("Created the table ".$aTables[$iIndex]."<BR>");}
    // -- Fill the table --
    $this->sPdoQuery = "REPLACE `".$sNewDBName."`.`".$aTables[$iIndex]."` SELECT * FROM `".$_SESSION['DB_name']."`.`".$aTables[$iIndex]."`";
    $bSuccess = $this->PdoSqlReturnTrue();
    if(!$bSuccess ){echo("Could not fill table: ".$aTables[$iIndex]."<BR>");}
    else{echo("Filled table ".$aTables[$index]."<BR>");}
}
```

}