# how to import Specific row from access to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Is there any solution I can possibly import a certain rows from Access to MySQL? or not? Can anyone give me a query to do in MySQL to import a certain row from the main table to the other table?

Comment: add more details please...

Comment: You want to import from a dump?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You may connect to Access db and MySQL and in the Access connection perform `SELECT` queries and on MySQL perform `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Please ignore, I misread your question thinking you were trying to copy data from one table into another. I didn't realise you were trying to import rows from Access to MySQL.**

---

`INSERT INTO table1 SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2`

Here is a old stackoverflow post that gives you even more details:
[Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates)

And some more additional information:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_insertrowfromtable.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you need to connect to two databases, for example using PDO. Below I assume that you now Access and MySQL table structures.

```
$access = new PDO( ... ); // insert your MS Access DSN, perhaps via ODBC
$mysql = new PDO(...); // the same with MySQL

// you need to check here if connections were successful

$query_acc = $access->query('SELECT * FROM AccessTableName');

$query_mysql = $mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO MySQLTableName VALUES(%val1, %val2, %val3 ...)');

while($row = $query_acc->fetchAll()){ // choose the method you like most
  $query_mysql->bindValue('%val1', $row['val1']);
  // do the same with other fields
  // ...
  $query_mysql->execute();
}
```

Perhaps the code can be optimized, but as you can see it's quite simple.