# import access csv without duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, csv, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a stock list that is given to me in .csv format. I cannot change the csv and need to do all my validation through Access 2007-2013.

I've created an append query to import my data into a table from CSV.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( tblfield1, tblfield2, tblfield3, tblfield4 )
SELECT [File#csv].[columnname1], [File#csv].[columnname2], [File#csv].[columnname3], [File#csv].[columnname4]
FROM [File#csv] IN '' [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437
;DATABASE=c:\your\filepath\here];
```

What I need it to do is import without duplicates, it seems a solution is to import the data to a temp table then copy without dupes from there.

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.Field1=destTable.Field1 and
                       SrcTable.Field2=DestTable.Field2...etc.)
                 )
```

(SQL taken from: [Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates))

This seems like a poor solution however. Is there a way to use a left join in the query to accomplish both tasks at once?

EDIT: I have made some progress.

```
  INSERT INTO tblDestination ( destfield1, destfield2, destfield3, destfield4 )
    SELECT filename1.[field1], filename1.[(field2], filename1.[field3], filename1.[field4]
    FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437)
    ;DATABASE=D:\your\file\path].filename.csv AS filename1 LEFT JOIN tblDestination ON filename1.[fieldX] = tblDestination.destfieldX
    WHERE (((filename1.[FieldX])= Is Null));
```

Edit: Solution is

```
  INSERT INTO tblDestination ( destfield1, destfield2, destfield3, destfield4 )
    SELECT filename1.[field1], filename1.[(field2], filename1.[field3], filename1.[field4]
    FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437)
    ;DATABASE=D:\your\file\path].filename.csv AS filename1 LEFT JOIN tblDestination ON filename1.[fieldX] = tblDestination.destfieldX
WHERE (((tblDestination.Field1) Is Null) AND ((tblDestination.Field2) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What I need though is an AND statement to only exclude the row if ALL fields are equal"

You seem to already have the right idea?

I'm using `OR` in the WHERE clause as a single mismatch means it's a different record

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination 
(destfield1, destfield2, destfield3, destfield4 )
SELECT filename1.[field1], filename1.[(field2], filename1.[field3], filename1.[field4]
FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437;
DATABASE=D:\your\file\path].filename.csv] AS filename1 
LEFT JOIN tblDestination 
ON  filename1.[field1] = tblDestination.destfield1
AND filename1.[field2] = tblDestination.destfield2
AND filename1.[field3] = tblDestination.destfield3
AND filename1.[field4] = tblDestination.destfield4
WHERE (
filename1.[Field1] IS NULL OR
filename1.[Field2] IS NULL OR 
filename1.[Field3] IS NULL OR 
filename1.[Field4] IS NULL
);
```

Comment: That looks like the right SQL but i'm getting "Cannot join on Memo, OLE or Hyperlink Object [spits out the contents of where]"

Comment: I guess one of your fields must be a memo. This makes your other solution a lot less 'poor' as it works and this one doesn't!

Comment: Your solution is fine. I needed to tweak the SQL a little. Thankyou very much for the help.

Instead of filename1.[field1] I had to use tblDestination.destfield1