# Comparing sql tables and

Tags: php, sql

I want to know how to compare two tables, and if they have the same values show them.

My original table is `user_information`, and there are 30 other tables with different names, but all of them have
the same columns which are `email`, `name` and `website`.

How to compare `user_information` table with all the other 30 tables automatically and that includes any new table I will add later.

Comment: show some dummy data and what you tried

Comment: But why 30 tables with the same columns???

Comment: you should build a better database schema

Comment: If you want to merge the data from the tables without duplicates, read this: [Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates)

Comment: You never need 30 tables with the same data. Just add a new column to separate.

Comment: 30 table because each member of the website have a table or there is another way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, by adding another column which says which member of the website the data belongs too. Or are you saying you only have one row of data in each table? I really hope you're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is basically this (sql-server):

```
Select email, name, website from table1
intersect
Select email, name, website from table2 ....
```

And so on.

Should do the trick.

If you're running the query against a MySQL database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, name, website FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
USING (email, name, website);
```

Comment: but that means that i have to add the tables name manually isn't there a way to make it automatically like: Select email, name, website from §current_user_table

Comment: There is. But first, what kind of database are you using?

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to just join them all, but here goes:
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='<your_database_name>';
This should give you the table names. Filter it with LIKE if needed.
Then (and this is bad for performance), use a cursor to join the tables in pairs, as stated in my answer. Basically, for each table, join with the next one and see which rows they both contain. If, after processing all the tables, the result still contains rows, then all the tables contain those rows.