# how to insert data in mysql database using mysqli with data checking no same "id" in same "date"

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

guy's i need  your help. im trying to make an insert form with php with this condition.

"id cant be same in same date"

my database name is : "ssl",
table name is : "try"
with table col: "id", "date", "name", "city"

im have try a lot to make this but still get some eror. but when i delete the php script for checking it can running well..

please help me. im really apreciated when you give me an example of that.

sorry for my english and sorry im still newbie and need study more for something like this

this my script for insert

```html
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "silo");


// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// Attempt insert query execution
$sql="Insert into termocouple 
        Select * from temp1";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Data inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "Data inserted Failed " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: can you paste your existing code here?

Comment: my insert data from the other table.
i use insert and go to select the other table

Comment: i need to make a checker in there. that can restrict the user insert a duplicate data. i use this for a checker
"id cant be same in the same date"

Comment: "id cant be same in same date" do you mean that in the form, the value for "id" should be different from "date"?

Comment: and is your form method get or post?

Comment: let me explain my problem.
my insert function using data from the other table like copying data from that table.
and my problem is. i need to make a restriction to the user while inserting the data. the user cannot inserted the same data

Comment: i'm not using a form.. im copying data from the other table

Comment: you know what i mean bro?

Comment: so you want to copy all data from "temp1" to "termocouple" and skip those entries where the id and date already exist?

Comment: yapz.. like that..
or just make the user cant be inser duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

can i just use something like this?
i get from [Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates)

```html
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO termocouple
SELECT no,tanggal,silo,... 
FROM temp1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (temp1.no=termocuple.no and
                       temp1.tanggal=termocouple.s_tanggal...etc.)
                 )";
                 ?>
```