# Oracle 11g Insert into from another table that has duplicates

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, insert, duplicates

Ok so I have 2 new tables: Client and Contract. I'm gonna focus on the first one as they have the same structure. Client looks like:

```
+-----------+---------+
| client_id |  name   |
+-----------+---------+
| Value 1   | Value 2 |
+-----------+---------+
```

And created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
  client_id varchar2(15)  NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(100)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Client_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
) ;
```

Also I have an old table: old_contracts looking like:

```
+------------+----------+------+
| contractid | clientid | name |
+------------+----------+------+
| con1       | cli1     | n1   |
| con2       | cli2     | n2   |
| con3       | cli2     | n2   |
| con4       | cli3     | n3   |
| con5       | cli3     | n3   |
+------------+----------+------+
```

Defined:

```
CREATE TABLE old_contracts(
  contractid varchar2(15)  NOT NULL
  clientid varchar2(15)  NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(100)  NOT NULL
) ;
```

I want to take the data from old_contract and insert it into Client.

---

This old_contracts table has rows with duplicate clientid (one client can have more than one contract) but I don't want to have duplicates on Client table so I am doing this:

```
INSERT INTO Client (
  client_id,
  name
) SELECT DISTINCT
  clientid,
  name
FROM old_contracts;
```

to not get duplicates. Anyway, I'm getting this error:

> Error SQL: ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER.CLIENT_PK) violated
>
> 00001.00000 - "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"

What's going on? I believe the *DISTINCT* keyword was going to do the thing.

---

I've also tried adding a **WHERE NOT EXISTS** clause as suggested in related posts (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates)), but the result I'm getting is the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the name is not always the same for a given clientid.

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO Client (
 client_id,
  name
) SELECT clientid,
  max(name)
FROM old_contracts
GROUP BY clientid;
```

Comment: This let me insert the data, but now I've got another problem:
When I try to do the same thing with the contract table (which has field Client as foreign key (contract_client_fk) to referenced to client.client_id) I get "ORA-02291: integrity constraint (user.contract_client_fk) violated - parent key not found"

Comment: Must say that client column in Contract table is nullable.

Comment: Nullable is not an issue here... but since you have populated `Client` with all `client_id`s that exist in `old_contracts`, I see no way how you could violate that constraint when you populate `Contract` with `old_contracts`. Maybe a little mistake that made you try to insert the `contract_id` into the `client_id` column or something like that?

Comment: Ok forget what I said. This issue whas related to a typo. Thanks for all.

Comment: @KevinRomero - is this the right solution for the business problem though? I agree with ammoQ, it is likely that the original problem was caused by having more than one `name` associated with the same `clientid`, for at least one `clientid`. In this case, the solution offered here essentially says "pick any name that was associated with the `clientid` in the old table and use it for the new table; ignore all the other names for the same `clientid`". There are other choices, for example use the longest name, or the shortest one, or the one associated with the most recent contract, etc.

Comment: @mathguy: you are right, I've simply shown the easiest workaround, but there may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: The bigger point about this is that the decision (what to do when we have different names for the same client) should be made by business managers, not by the IT department. This is why I think it should be part of the requirement itself, and not part of the solution.

Comment: @mathguy: In my opinion, it's best to use the simple strategy from my answer, but also create a report of all those cases and give that to the business manager to process case-by-case (or not at all, depending on the consequences)

Comment: @mathguy you're right. In this case it's for a course I'm taking at university, so the simple thing ammoQ showed is enought, but I do agree that a decision should be make in other cases.

Comment: @KevinRomero - At the very least, when you turn this in, explain what choice you made (or - in this case - elected not to make). It should bring bonus points from a good teacher, for understanding the issue and documenting it - pretty much along the lines ammoQ suggested.

Comment: @mathguy yes, we did! But just like you said "it should bring bonus points from a _good_ teacher" haha