# SQL Insert rows into another table if they aren't duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

Hello I'm having trouble figuring out how to insert rows that are not duplicates from one table to another, I have in mind something like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1
       SELECT id, name, lastname FROM Table2
              WHERE id.Table1 != id.Table2 
              AND name.Table1 != name.Table2 
              AND lastname.Table1 != lastname.Table2
```

How to write that condition that specifies not to insert if it already exists?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I needed to match only certain columns since the tables contain identity 1,1 my solution is as follows:

```
    MERGE Table1 as t1
    USING (SELECT name, lastname FROM Table2) AS t2 (name, lastname) 
    ON t1.[name] = t2.[name] AND t1.[lastname] = t2.[lastname] 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN
    INSERT (name, lastname) VALUES (t2.[name], t2.[lastname]);
```

Of course this is just an example I'm using a lot more columns and data

edit: not a duplicate since the solutions presented match the entire table

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012

Comment: @SeanLange Ah, thought I found this through the MySQL tag.

Comment: You may want to check out this thread where it looks like your question has been answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but none of that worked for my case I found the solution with MERGE

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach this is to use the `except` operator:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT id, name, lastname FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT id, name, lastname FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I forgot to mention that I needed to match certain columns but not all, I found the solution with merge

Answer (score 1):

You may use `NOT EXISTS`. Please be aware that table name is always **before** attribute name.

```
 INSERT INTO Table1
   SELECT id, name, lastname 
   FROM Table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT * 
             FROM Table1 
             WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id AND 
                   Table1.name = Table2.name AND 
                   Table1.lastname = Table2.lastname
           )
```