# Updating specific columns from Table A to Table B in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need two columns from Table A to update in Table B, 'Emp_Id' and 'Name' are the two columns.

What I've done so far is just inserted Table A's columns to Table B, but that just inserts the same data twice:

```
INSERT INTO UserLeaves(Emp_id,Name)
SELECT Emp_Id,Name
FROM UserInfo
```

I just need the new data from Table A to concatenate into Table B.

Comment: So have you tried an `UPDATE`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I've tried using "UPDATE UserLeaves SET UserLeaves.Name = UserInfo.Name FROM UserLeaves JOIN UserInfo ON UserLeaves.Emp_id = UserInfo.Emp_Id" but that doesn't do it.

Comment: What do you mean "concatenate into Table B"??   Give us an example.

Comment: @TabAlleman So TableA has some data that is also in Table B, if I update Table A, Table B should update the table with new data, and not old data+new data

Comment: Still unclear.   Please edit your question with sample data and desired results, unless Larnu's answer below happens to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @TabAlleman Lamu's answer worked, sorry if I wasn't more clear, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Repub619 If Lamu's answer worked for you then marked that answer as accepted so that his answer will not get downvote as I see a downvote for a correct answer.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to `INSERT` new records, and not `UPDATE` any existing records:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Emp_ID, [Name])
SELECT A.Emp_ID, A.[Name]
FROM TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.EmpID
                  FROM TableB B
                  WHERE B.EmpID = A.EmpID);
```

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777493/updating-specific-columns-from-table-a-to-table-b-in-sql-server#comment82516233_47777493) comment, user wants to update the existing data and need to insert new data.

Comment: Question and comment does seem to conflict. Answer is based on the current question. If the OP is after an `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, then possibly a candidate for a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: A comment for a reason on the Downvote would be great, considering the OP says this worked (although not marked as solution).

Comment: @Repub619 If Lamu's answer worked for you then marked that answer as accepted so that his answer will not get downvote as I see a downvote for a correct answer.

Comment: @Larnu will accept after it lets me. Currently can't do so

Comment: Thanks for the marked solution. Still would love to hear from the downvoter. :)